# how to change columns data to row in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to change the give format of data

```
Subject       T1     T2       T3
GK            A
Drawing       A-
GK                    B
Drawing               A
GK                             A-
Drawing                        A
```

And I want this in below format

```
Subject   T1     T2   T3
GK         A     B    A-
Drawing    A-    A    A
```

Can any body help me to change in crystal report...

Comment: create a grouop with subject... and add the data... but before can you post what have you tried and where are you struck

Comment: As upper table i have got now i want to change in below table format.. i tried to group subject wise but it didnot work

Comment: can you explain what are you getting by using this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subreports.
My suggestion would be, create a subreport for each row i.e. for each Subject. For each sub report- write a query that give a resultset of grade of each student in a single subject.
Thereafter, import the sub reports. The number of subreports would be equal to total number of subjects, which you can import in report footer section(this created some trouble for me when I imported sub reports in detail section of the report)
hopefully this helps!